# VSCodeでターミナルの上の境界線の色を変更したい

Tags: vscode

VSCodeでターミナルの上の境界線の色を変更したいのですが、
下記のキャプチャのような設定ですと、
拡張機能 (例えばGit HistoryやGit Graphなど)を開いている際は、境界線の指定が効きません。
どのようにしたら良いでしょうか？

◆キャプチャ
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuAu6.png

◆動画説明 (音声あり)
https://youtu.be/kKoJPQki3pQ

◆MicroSoft公式サイト
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Comment: この辺の記事 [Themable window border](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_themable-window-border), [Window border](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#window-border), [User Interface](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface) から考えると、`panel.border`あたりが該当しそうです。[Panel colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#panel-colors)

Comment: ありがとうございます。(キャプチャに載せていまして) panel.boredeは適用済みです

Comment: 無さそうなら、[vscodeのIssues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) に質問や要望を上げてみるか、`panel.background`でパネル全体の色を少し変えて代替手段とするかあたりでしょうか。